# Visualização de perfil X Tempo

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma ferramenta que permite acompanhar quantas pessoas estão visualizando meu perfil num intervalo de tempo. A intenção era saber se encontro algum gráfico parecido com o de pontuação:

[image: timeline de pontuação]

Eu não encontrei referência a esse tipo de informação aqui no site, nem sei se ela é plausível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gráficos não tem, mas tem no perfil como @rray indicou:

> [image: perfil]

Se [isto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181523/198279) estiver correto, então uma query seria isto, top 100 mais visitados:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/681503/top-100-perfis-mais-visitados

É possivel filtrar pelo ID usando a coluna `users.Views`, mas infelizmente não tem uma coluna de data, então é impossível adaptar até o momento

Comment: Precisa ver se tem algo no SEDE.

Comment: Nem conhecia o data explorer. Tava vendo aqui, pelo menos no modelo relacional fornecido pelo Database Schema, não tem uma maneira fácil/óbvia de pegar meu perfil alguns dias atrás e comparar com o de hoje. Se eu quiser fazer isso, preciso fazer manualmente. Muitíssimo grato!

Comment: Tem um contagem de visitas, é o número total de a criação do usário. Fica na aba perfil no canto direito.

Comment: @rray baita gafe minha :p, certa vez li no sede que tinha parado de funcionar, mas talvez tenha sido o bug

Comment: Pois é, eu conhecia esse visualizações desde a criação, mas eu queria saber se tinha por data. Estou estudando isso para ver se meu perfil tem impacto em trazer as pessoas para o TotalCross, assim como o perfil do Shai Almog traz gente para o Code Name 1

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado então mesmo com data.explorer não consegui, o máximo que tenho de coluna na query é o `users.Views`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sou eternamente grato! Vou criar esse gráfico dando `fetch` na informação e povoando minha própria base de dados. Valeu!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de uma olhada nisto, creio ser uma proposta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308967/1518921

Comment: Essa *query* tá certa. Mas não tem histórico, né?

Comment: Não tem como @bigown, só tem a coluna `users.views` para usar, se existisse uma tabela que tivesse `views` e `date` a parte com tais dados talvez seria possivel, eu não sei se internamente existe, da uma olhada no link acima da proposta, tá meio parada, mas parece legal. A query ali foi um exemplo que encontrei, só adicionei pq achei interessante :)